# echo get syntax in quote

Tags: php, syntax

I have a script that send user to another url everytime he click (first click - first url, secound cluck - secound url etc.)

Here is the script:

```
<?php           
function urlredirect()
{
$value=0;
$url =array(
'http://www.link1.com/',
'http://www.link2.com/',
'http://www.link3.com/',
'http://www.link4.com/',
'http://www.link5.com/',
); 
$urlc = count($url)-1;
if ($_COOKIE["cooki_name"]=='') 
  {
setcookie("cooki_name", $value,time()+86400);
header ("Location: $url[$value]"); 
  }
  if ($_COOKIE["cooki_name"]!='') 
       {
  $getcookie=htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["cooki_name"]);
    if($urlc >$getcookie)
  {
  $getcookie=$getcookie+1;
  }
  setcookie("cooki_name", $getcookie,time()+86400);
  header ("Location: $url[$getcookie]");
  }
  }
   urlredirect(); 
    ?>
```

Now I need to add some echo and I do not know the right syntax. Echo from get:

script.php?code=something

```
<?php           
function urlredirect()
{
$value=0;
$url =array(
'http://www.link1.com/HERE-IS-THE-PLACE-WHERE-I-NEED-TO-ADD-code',
'http://www.link2.com/',
'http://www.link3.com/',
....
```

I was trying to add it by echo $_GET["code"]; but I fail.

Comment: You can try $_REQUEST['code'];

Comment: You mean something like this:
      'http://www.link1.com/$_REQUEST['code']',

Comment: no. i mean instead of using $_GET["code"]; you can try $_REQUEST['code'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

construct your array like this to paas the url parameter in url

```
$url =array(
 'http://www.link1.com/?code=some_value',
 'http://www.link2.com/?code=some_value',
 'http://www.link3.com/?code=some_value',
 'http://www.link4.com/?code=some_value',
 'http://www.link5.com/?code=some_value',
);
```

Now on your redirected page you can use

```
echo $_GET['code'];
```

**Edit** Based on comments

```
$url =array(
 'http://www.link1.com/'.$_GET['code'],
 'http://www.link2.com/'.$_GET['code'],
 'http://www.link3.com/'.$_GET['code'],
 'http://www.link4.com/'.$_GET['code'],
 'http://www.link5.com/'.$_GET['code'],
);
```

Comment: But code is different every time so I cant add it to script.
This value is generated by other script.

Comment: @Luca If the code is different every time, you can use `$_GET['code']` to get that. This is only example I shown you.

Comment: The problem is that I am noob in php and I do not know how to add $_GET['code'] to array (the value that get passing).

Comment: For example I was trying do do something like this:

       $arr = $_GET["code"]; 

       $url = array('http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com.$arr',

Comment: @Luca If you are new in PHP then read some books of PHP to get your basics clear after that try this hard coding work. Start with small.

Comment: Im reading tutorials right now and unfortunaly I cand find this :( I know problem is in syntax.

Comment: value from scipt.php?code=value must by added to arrey, for example code=car so arrey after that looks like ('url1/car', 'url2/car'). I need to know what code I have to add to arrey to pass the value from url to script.

Comment: @Luca Try this `header ("Location: " . $url . $_GET['code']);`

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much Yogesh!:) I was adding .$_GET before ' and that was the problem. Thank you one more time :)